# Should we approve an edit which removes broken a URL?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was reviewing [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4981108).

The editor had removed a broken(404) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link. So I approved it. But it said it already had been rejected.

How is it *not* improving the post?

Comment: I would have approved that, but note that the link was *repairable*; I've [done so now](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5825878/revisions).

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can I repair those urls?

Comment: Remove the account name from the URL.

Comment: Be very cautious about removing information - even if the link is presently non-functional it doesn't mean it always will be, or that an interested party can't find it from another source.   But once it's gone, most viewers may have no way of knowing it was ever there.

Answer (score 9):

I argue that you should NOT simply remove a broken link. Removing will (per Chris Stratton's comment) lose information. If the link is repairable (that is, you can find what it's supposed to point to, or the wayback machine has it), then I like to put the revised link in parenthesis after the original. That way no information is lost.

Comment: +1 for thinking of archives like the Wayback Machine.