# Is it ok to remove specific version numbers from URLs to documentation?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This edit suggestion proposes to alter a link so that the newest version of the mentioned Python game is provided:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8186027

The original answer points to Version 01.02.00, Nov. 13, the corrected URL would point (right now) to version 01.09.00.

Here are some pros and cons around altering URLs:

- (+) Referring to newest versions in ICT somehow means "staying alive". Good thing. Sometimes, it is some work to find a newest version.
- (-) Text written in a post referring to a URL may become faulty if the URL is changed without adapting the text.
- (-) A different URL should rather be a comment. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258362/should-we-approve-an-edit-which-removes-broken-a-url), it is proposed to append a newer or valid URL in brackets, which is also a good idea.
- (-) In the edit suggestion mentioned, if I visit the page with the original URL, the first thing I read is "Latest version: 01.09.00". So here is not much use for that edit.
- (-) Somehow, altering an URL feels like riding over the OPs intention.

I would have rejected the edit suggestion, but it was approved in the meantime.

What do you think? Is it ok to edit URLs to newest versions, if it doesn't break the text? Better leave a comment, or just add the new URL?

Comment: I don't know if this is equivalent, but I frequently edit MSDN links to omit the version number (and then test to ensure it's still the same link). In general, such a link is not meant to be version-specific.

Comment: There's no need to throw the version number in a PyPI url unless you're referring to a specific version. The text for that answer is clearly just pointing at the package, so it makes sense to drop the version number in the url.

Comment: Thanks John and Kevin, I see some interesting aspects of URLs and versions now. I think, being careful with editing URLs is necessary, but there are things that are clearly not meant version specific. The version might be an obstacle in the long term. It is up to the editor to make a reasonable decision.

Comment: I don't agree that _removing_ the version to point to the _latest_ is harmless as long as you check the "compatibility": what if the answer is no longer relevant to some "future current version" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is it ok to edit URLs to newest versions, if it doesn't break the text?

Yes, as pointed out in the comments, if it's not meant to be a version-specific URL then it should be fine.

But please note that this doesn't apply to the suggested edit you link to. The answer now points to the latest version, but still claims it's a version from November 2013. This edit should have been rejected, or improved, not simply accepted.

Comment: That's what I mean with "become faulty ... without adapting the post text". Thx a lot, the discussion becomes clear to me.

Answer (score 6):

I think @hvd's answer is spot on, *if the latest documentation reflects the same behavior as the original.*

This may not apply to Python in specific, but consider the following scenario:

- An answer links to version 1.0 documentation which indicates that a structure behaves in a particular fashion. "Function *foo()* will iterate across a list and remove items that meet the configured criteria." At the time the answer is written, this is the most current version, and is the version used in the original question.
- A well-meaning user updates the documentation to version 1.2, which happens to be the latest. Now, the documentation has been updated due to changes in the implementation: "Function *foo()* will iterate across a list *in a thread-safe fashion* and remove items that meet the configured criteria."

In this situation, the update is actually invalid as it reflects a change not only to the documentation, but to the underlying implementation as well. Depending on the question, changing the implementation version may actually invalidate the answer, or mislead future visitors. The original question may not have been against a particular version of a language, but an answer is definitely written against a particular version or versions.

Therefore I think that the correct answer is that one should not just blindly update documentation to the "latest" revision, but rather take the time to confirm that the original and the revised version reflect the same information, and don't fundamentally change the meaning of the answer.

As mentioned, this may not be relevant to Python, or to a language whose documentation standards include some sort of changelist (eg. "Prior to 0.9.0, had side effect *x*. Subsequent to 0.9.1, *x* did not apply, but *y* did instead.) It should be something to keep in mind for other languages, especially those who are in rapid flux or a pre-release state.