Should a link redirect to a specific version or the current version?
I came across this suggested edit, and here is a screenshot:

The edit simply updates the link from a specific version, to the "current" version. The old link is already working.
As the new link could break because of a software update, or be in conflict with the answer, should this type of edit be accepted? How can we know if we should use the link at specific version of at the "actual"/"current" version?

I feel it really depends on the situation, in certain cases it might be better to link specific versions since the feature might get removed in future versions (This has happened to me where I linked to the "latest" docs and the link basically broke due to version changes). In this case though the link is about a feature that will very likely stay (it is part of SQL standard and has been there since quite some time) so linking the "current" / latest version shouldn't be a problem.

@AbdulAzizBarkat that assumes that their URL structure also stays the same.

@RyanM You mean the link to that particular page changes in future versions? That's also a possibility yes, but I'd like to bank on cool URIs not changing. :P

@RyanM if the URL structure changes, then even even the old one could become obsolete and broken. Many documentation links online are broken in that way - the parent company decided to change them and suddenly old posts/articles/whatever are incomplete. At which point it doesn't really matter which one you used. At most the one with the version embedded in the URL might suggest what it was pointing to at one point.

@VLAZ it's significantly less likely with versioned URLs, though.  They provide a permalink (a cool URI, if you will), while still allowing newer versions of the docs to be restructured.

It's case-by-case, but I've had a suggested edit on 1 of my answers that did something like this and I rejected it, because then my answer would not work, because the library was completely re-written for the current/latest version. There was already an answer that adapted the solution for the current/latest version, so I opted to just maintain my answer for old versions for those who can't bump major versions. I think it's just safer to keep the link to the old/specific version, unless you can also verify the answer still works for the "current"/"latest".

@GinoMempin the issue is that, the current version can change because of a rewrite for almost all links

@RyanM I feel like people who use a URL scheme that includes things like /current/ are implicitly making a commitment to keep that scheme stable.

@KarlKnechtel and yet... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/install-win32.html (works), https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-win32.html (dead link)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-windows.html works. Is that really a change to the "URL structure"? I think they only changed how they refer to the Windows platform (starting with 9.0). If the question is about the technology generally rather than a specific version, then there's value in keeping it up to date. Making it point to the current version by an explicit version number would require a change every time; using current would require much less frequent updates.

(And if a new version obviates the answer, then the whole thing should be updated anyway.)

@KarlKnechtel maybe this is a better example of what Ryan M wants to say: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1997481/revisions (you can just remove the version part from the url and there is an auto redirect to the latest version) although in this case they broke the URL for all versions and documentation of the linked version just stopped existing (The specific version there was release quite some time ago though).

I mostly agree that this is very dependent on the context, and has to be decided on a case-by-case/question-by-question basis. However, I think one part of this edit - the http -> https change - is pretty non-controversial and we should always make this update where the https version of the URL is a valid link.

@VLAZ The situation you describe has been a particular issue with microsoft.com URLs in the past. I try to update the redirecting links before they become broken, but I do often have to compare the content at the new URL to the content at an archived version at the old URL, and then decide whether the information at the "current" location has diverged too far from the relevant information that the link was originally a source for.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295158/is-it-ok-to-remove-specific-version-numbers-from-urls-to-documentation?rq=1

I think it's always going to depend on the context of a given post.
In the linked answer (with the caveat that I'm not at all familiar with PostgreSQL's versioning), it doesn't seem like a specific version really has anything to do with the answer itself, nor the question being asked. The core concern is definitely the functionality, not a particular version's feature set.
In cases like this, where versioning isn't really in the discussion, linking to the current version of the documentation seems very reasonable to me, and I'd argue is somewhat more useful to readers than linking whatever version happened to be current at time of posting, since the current-version link will be "timeless" in a sense– it's always going to reflect the most up-to-date info.
Now, for a question or answer that's more version-conscious, or which talks explicitly about a certain version, or legacy functionality that's no longer available? That kind of edit could almost certainly be harmful– but that's still going to depend on the specific context of that Q/A post.

Link rot was brought up in the comments as a concern here, but I see no compelling reason to believe that version-specific or "current"-version links are broadly more or less likely to break over time. Preferring one style over the other for this reason alone is an attempt to read the future, which I think is silly. Link what's most useful– future editors will handle those links if they break, in the future.

Django in particular would remove very old version of documentations, specially if there's a security issue that is solved by newer versions. They want people to not even attempt to use old versions. Every version of the documentation has the compilation of all depreciation notes, so you always know what happened with your favorite method/class/parameter.

@Braiam Impressive. I feel like everyone should do it that way.

I suppose it could depend on exactly what the question is. But most likely any question that refers to a software product is going to be about some specific functional aspect of that product. It's quite possible that that functionality will change with future versions, which would make a link to the current version confusing.
If the question is about, say, how to work around a bug or some quirky behavior, referencing the current version is highly problematic. The bug may be fixed by now. Or in general, the behavior of any feature may have changed.
I regularly search for help on various software products and find pages that describe behavior totally different from what I see on my computer. Often I can say, "Oh, they must have written this about an older version". But sometimes it's not obvious, and it's just confusing.
Not entirely relevant, but just yesterday I was searching for questions about JavaScript where, I quickly learned, the issue related to some security features. And those features have changed over time, so that several answers I found just don't work any more. Apparently browser makers decided that was a security hole and plugged it. No one gave a link to an old browser, which is why I say this isn't entirely relevant. But, in retrospect at least, a good answer would have had to say, "this worked in browser X version Y." Then when I found the solution didn't work I could look at version numbers and say, "oh, X is up to version Y+20 now, things may well have changed", versus, "hmm, but I'm using version Y and it doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm not doing something right."
Thus, I think it's better to reference a specific version when possible. If the post is old enough that that version is no longer available, well, my next question would be whether the current version exhibits the same behavior or if the question has become moot.

As zcoop98 said, it strongly depends on the context, but in general I'd lean more towards "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" - or in this context - if the link works (and it is not predictable that it will break), don't change it.
My example for this would be Qt Documentation. There are often changes between major (and sometimes even minor) revisions, some of these change deprecate entire functions (or classes). Changing the link to the "current" documentation might break answers, just like changing a link from a documentation for Python 2.x to Python 3.x arguing the 3.x is "newer"/"current"...

So, from what you say, this edit should not be accepted as the old link works ?

In essence, yes, I'd probably lean to not accepting that edit, based on the fact that the link works and the answer is based on this very version of the software. (Unless I am confident that the specific version is truly not relevant to the answer - context is important)
